# Publish Layout - randomly reorders fields EE 5.2.2

Tags: control-panel, bug, publish-layout

I updated an EE 2.10 site to EE 5.2.2 a couple of weeks ago.

Today the client requested some new fields be added to a channel. I added them and went to move them into the correct position in the publish layout. Only one moved and saved. The other field stayed at the bottom despite movign and saving a few times.

I kept trying and now all the fields move into a random order each time I save the layout. How do I get the layout to work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, this sounds like a bug I had in EE3 (https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/21971/Layout-Order-Messing-Up#comment_17258). My workaround was making a new layout vs. editing an existing one. I'd recommend giving that a shot (a simple layout to start) to see how that goes.

Answer (score -2):

To reorder the fields I'm using Low Reoder that permit to sort entries:

https://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder

Comment: this is not reordering entries but reordering fields in the publish layout.